# How do display a volume control for an Action in the Google Home app

Tags: android, google-smart-home, google-assistant

I am developing a [Smart Home Action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/create) and have managed to get my soundbar-like device to link in the Google Home app, where I can control its volume using voice commands. I do not see a volume control in the app though, like I do for other speaker-like devices such as the Google Home or my TV.

When I tap on my device in the Google Home app (linked as a test account), I just see Device Settings, and no controls at all.

This is the SYNC response for my device:

```
{
  "requestId": "7848726039212384681",
  "payload": {
    "agentUserId": "robin@mccorkell.me.uk",
    "errorCode": null,
    "debugString": null,
    "devices": [
      {
        "id": "ampcontrol@mccorkell.me.uk",
        "type": "action.devices.types.SOUNDBAR",
        "traits": [
          "action.devices.traits.OnOff",
          "action.devices.traits.MediaState",
          "action.devices.traits.Volume",
          "action.devices.traits.TransportControl"
        ],
        "name": {
          "defaultNames": null,
          "name": "Amplifier",
          "nicknames": null
        },
        "willReportState": false,
        "notificationSupportedByAgent": false,
        "roomHint": null,
        "deviceInfo": null,
        "attributes": {
          "transportControlSupportedCommands": [],
          "volumeMaxLevel": 100,
          "volumeCanMuteAndUnmute": false,
          "levelStepSize": 10,
          "queryOnlyOnOff": true
        },
        "customData": null,
        "otherDeviceIds": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the QUERY response for my device:

```
{
  "requestId": "15675955780684435642",
  "payload": {
    "errorCode": null,
    "debugString": null,
    "devices": {
      "ampcontrol@mccorkell.me.uk": {
        "online": true,
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "errorCode": null,
        "on": true,
        "currentVolume": 96
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our teams are constantly working to improve Google Home App and the controls available in the UI. Right now for certain device types we are only able to display controls for certain traits. For these devices the controls are always available through voice.
Your Sync response looks right for a soundbar device. If you need the touch controls for Soundbar devices, I recommend to create a feature request in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://buganizer.corp.google.com/).

Comment: Which device type/trait is necessary to get a volume control to show up in the Home app? I don't necessarily need it to present as a Soundbar, I can change the device type to anything that supports the Volume trait.

Comment: It looks like as of somewhat recently, the Google Home app shows a (rather primitive) volume up and down button for both Soundbar and Speaker devices. While not as good as the sliding volume control displayed for Google devices, it's a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Not all device types & traits provide UI features in the Google Home App (GHA) and directly open up the device settings page upon tapping the device icon in GHA. This is default behavior for some device types.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with it, you can set your type to "action.devices.types.LIGHT"
and use "action.devices.traits.Brightness" to control your volume.

This fix worked for me, but if you found a more correct solution I'd be happy to know.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).